# Ordering data from multiple processes in Erlang

Tags: concurrency, parallel-processing, erlang, multicore

I am making a program that categorises ID numbers into Rooms and Groups. I'm trying to order some output from multiple parallel processes but the output is coming out like this

```
{'C003','Group A',1}
{'C002','Group B',3}
{'C015','Group C',5}
{'C016','Group D',7}
{'C003','Group A',2}
{'C002','Group B',4}
{'C015','Group C',6}
{'C016','Group D',8}
```

But I'd want it like this:

```
{'C003','Group A',1}
{'C003','Group A',2}
{'C002','Group B',3}
{'C002','Group B',4}
{'C015','Group C',5}
{'C015','Group C',6}
{'C016','Group D',7}   
{'C016','Group D',8}
```

I thought maybe I could send the numbers to a processes and have it somehow print them and their groups in order but I'm not sure how to do it while still having the processes happen in parallel. I thought a solution could be selective receive but I can't seem to figure it out that way either. Can anyone assist me with this ? 
This is a snippet of code from my main program 
Note: I am new to Erlang

```
-module(ppp).

-compile([export_all]).

categorise(L) ->

     Size = len(L) div 4,
     Rem = len(L) rem 4,    
     spawn(ppp, cat, [self(), 'Group A', L, 0, Size + Rem]),
     spawn(ppp, cat, [self(), 'Group B', L, (Size + Rem), Size]),
     spawn(ppp, cat, [self(), 'Group C', L, (2*Size + Rem), Size]),
     spawn(ppp, cat, [self(), 'Group D', L, (3*Size  + Rem), Size]), 
     wait(4). 

wait(0) -> {done};
wait(N) ->
receive
    done -> wait(N-1)
end.

cat(P, Name, L, Start, Elements) ->     
     Extract = lists:split(Start, L),   
     Group = element(2, Extract),   
     AGroup = lists:sublist(Group, Elements),
     spawn(ppp, putInRoom, [P, Name, AGroup]).

putInRoom(P, _, []) -> P ! done;

putInRoom(P, GroupName, [H|T]) -> 

if GroupName == 'Group A' ->        
    io:format("~w~n", [{'C003', GroupName, H}]),        
    putInRoom(P, GroupName, T);
    GroupName == 'Group B' -> 
    io:format("~w~n", [{'C002', GroupName, H}]),
    putInRoom(P, GroupName, T);
    GroupName == 'Group C' ->
    io:format("~w~n", [{'C015', GroupName, H}]),
    putInRoom(P, GroupName, T);
    GroupName == 'Group D' ->
    io:format("~w~n", [{'C016', GroupName, H}]),
    putInRoom(P, GroupName, T)
end.

len(L) -> 
    count(L, 0).

count([], Acc) -> Acc;

count([_|T], Acc) -> count(T, Acc + 1).
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with parallelism and everything to do with concurrency. The problem is synchronization since there is none between the processes. You need to synchronize the output in some way. Using sleeps will not work when you are highly loaded.

Comment: So the answer given by Kadaj is correct because he's suggested spawning these processes synchronously

Answer (score 0):

Instead of spawning the `putInRoom` process for each group, spawn for each element in the group.

```
-module(ppp).

-compile([export_all]).

categorise(L) ->

     Size = len(L) div 4,
     Rem = len(L) rem 4,    
     spawn(ppp, cat, [self(), 'Group A', L, 0, Size + Rem]),
     spawn(ppp, cat, [self(), 'Group B', L, (Size + Rem), Size]),
     spawn(ppp, cat, [self(), 'Group C', L, (2*Size + Rem), Size]),
     spawn(ppp, cat, [self(), 'Group D', L, (3*Size  + Rem), Size]), 
     wait(4). 

wait(0) -> {done};
wait(N) ->
receive
    done -> wait(N-1)
after 2000 ->
     ok
end.

cat(P, Name, L, Start, Elements) ->
     % io:format("cat: ~p L: ~p~n", [P,L]),     
     Extract = lists:split(Start, L),   
     Group = element(2, Extract),   
     AGroup = lists:sublist(Group, Elements),
     % io:format("AGroup: ~p~n", [AGroup]),
     lists:map(fun(G) ->
                 spawn(ppp, putInRoom, [P, Name, G])
               end, AGroup).

putInRoom(P, GroupName, H) -> 
    % io:format("putInRoom: ~p, List: ~p~n", [GroupName, H]),
    if GroupName == 'Group A' ->        
        io:format("~w~n", [{'C003', GroupName, H}]);
        GroupName == 'Group B' -> 
        io:format("~w~n", [{'C002', GroupName, H}]);
        GroupName == 'Group C' ->
        io:format("~w~n", [{'C015', GroupName, H}]);
        GroupName == 'Group D' ->
        io:format("~w~n", [{'C016', GroupName, H}])
    end,
    P ! done.

len(L) -> 
    count(L, 0).

count([], Acc) -> Acc;

count([_|T], Acc) -> count(T, Acc + 1).
```

It prints group by order.

```
2> ppp:categorise(lists:seq(1,8)).
{'C003','Group A',1}
{'C003','Group A',2}
{'C002','Group B',3}
{'C002','Group B',4}
{'C015','Group C',5}
{'C015','Group C',6}
{'C016','Group D',7}
{'C016','Group D',8}
{done}
```

Using a delay by adding `timer:sleep(100)`, between spawning the `cat` process. But then you kind of loose on the concurrent nature. So if you want to print the messages in order, you have to come up with a different algorithm.

```
-module(ppp).

-compile([export_all]).

categorise(L) ->

     Size = len(L) div 4,
     Rem = len(L) rem 4,    
     spawn(ppp, cat, [self(), 'Group A', L, 0, Size + Rem]),
     timer:sleep(100),
     spawn(ppp, cat, [self(), 'Group B', L, (Size + Rem), Size]),
     timer:sleep(100),
     spawn(ppp, cat, [self(), 'Group C', L, (2*Size + Rem), Size]),
     timer:sleep(100),
     spawn(ppp, cat, [self(), 'Group D', L, (3*Size  + Rem), Size]), 
     wait(4). 

wait(0) -> {done};
wait(N) ->
receive
    done -> wait(N-1)
after 2000 ->
     ok
end.

cat(P, Name, L, Start, Elements) ->
     % io:format("cat: ~p L: ~p~n", [P,L]),     
     Extract = lists:split(Start, L),   
     Group = element(2, Extract),   
     AGroup = lists:sublist(Group, Elements),
     % io:format("AGroup: ~p~n", [AGroup]),
     Pid = spawn(fun putInRoom2/0),
     Pid ! {P, cat, {Name, AGroup}}.

putInRoom2() -> 
    receive
        {P, cat, {_GroupName, []}} -> P ! done;
        {P, cat, {GroupName, L}} ->
            F = fun(G, [H|T]) ->
                    if
                        GroupName == 'Group A' ->        
                            io:format("~w~n", [{'C003', GroupName, H}]);
                        GroupName == 'Group B' -> 
                            io:format("~w~n", [{'C002', GroupName, H}]);
                        GroupName == 'Group C' ->
                            io:format("~w~n", [{'C015', GroupName, H}]);
                        GroupName == 'Group D' ->
                            io:format("~w~n", [{'C016', GroupName, H}])
                    end,
                    self() ! {P, cat, {G, T}}
                end,
            F(GroupName, L),
            putInRoom2()
    end.

len(L) -> 
    count(L, 0).

count([], Acc) -> Acc;

count([_|T], Acc) -> count(T, Acc + 1).
```

Comment: Thank you but why does this solution print them in order ? and wouldn't creating a process for each element incur a performance overhead with larger lists ?

Comment: This prints in order because it's spawns process in order. In your code it actually prints column wise `[1,2,3],[4,5,6]` means you get `1,4,2,5,3,6`. Not sure why it is. Maybe some scheduler thing? Regarding performance, in the current state the `putInRoom` function is very short lived. So I guess it wouldn't be that taxing. You can measure performance though.

Comment: The order is not what you expected because the you the spawning is async. Means, you spawn `cat` with `[1,2]`, `[3,4]` as data, the `putInRoom` displays `1`, but by the time is recurse and as the code is async, the second spawn executes which prints `3` and likewise. You can see that the print order changes when you add delay. Basically you want to think it like spawning processes and message passing as sync.

Comment: Can anyone provide a better answer. I don't mind down votes but I'm trying to learn too. :)